# Programmatically create return - Enterprise

Tags: magento-enterprise, rma

What function can be used to create a return in Magento Enterprise (RMA module).

It seems that all the regular functionality is built using the  `$_POST` variable, what if the data is being pulled from a third party, is there an easy way to do this without submitting a form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best advice I can give you is to try to simulate the code from the RMA create action from the admin controller. I don't know exactly how that looks, but I bet it gets the date from $_POST (like you said) and process it. Try to log the data send through POST to the action and replicate it's format. Then you can basically use the same code as in the action.